# How to get multi selection look up value in Power BI report?

Tags: lookup-column, reports, powerbi

I am new in Power BI and working on creating a simple report. I have 2 list - "Country" and "Test" which contain invoice amount. Country is multiselect look up in Test list.

I need to create report which will have a slicer dropdown of countries and below that will bind test list. I need to show the countries in Test list table visual but I am not able to get its values using `LOOKUPVALUE` function. It is showing blank. Below is what I tried:

```
Country = LOOKUPVALUE('Country'[Title],'Country'[ID],'Test'[CountryId])
```

I believe this is not working as the field is multiselect look up and "CountryId" is returning list of values. Can someone tell me how can I loop through that and populate the country value in the table visual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many phrase in google and finally got the way. [This](https://www.spguides.com/power-bi-report-using-people-picker-field/) link shows how to get values for people picker field and same solution I applied for multi select look up worked. Below is detailed steps in case someone facing same issue:

1. In Power BI Report, from Home tab click transform data button.
2. In this you can see all your source table. Open the table where you have multi select look up.
3. In this you will find `FieldValuesAsText` column. This field contains these kind fields values. you can directly select the expand icon for the `FieldValuesAsText` column and then disable all the available fields except the multi select look up column.
4. It will title as `FieldValuesAsText.multilookuptext`. You can rename it if you want or can use directly in your report to show the values.